# Are 1095-C forms obsolete under current law?

Tags: united-states, taxes

For the past several years I've received one of these `1095-C Employer-Provided Health Insurance Offer and Coverage` which lists myself, my dependents, and this table (e) for the *Months of Coverage* which has a X check mark in each row (covered individual) and column (months of the year).

I know vaguely these have something to do with the affordable care act to keep tabs on the citizens to make sure they retain some form of health care with penalties if you don't get check marks across the entire year.

The main question I have is: are these forms used for anything today, are they obsolete due to current law?

Some follow up questions:

- Were these forms every used for actually enforcing penalties?
- Is the state and or the federal government who primarily utilizes this information for something?
- Will these forms be abandoned in the near future?

Comment: Several states do have a penalty for not having health insurance (I believe MA, NJ, DC starting 2019; and CA, RI starting 2020), so maybe it will be used for those

Answer (score 2):

https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1095-c

> Form 1095-C is filed and furnished to any employee of an Applicable Large Employers (ALE) member who is a full-time employee for one or more months of the calendar. ALE members must report that information for all twelve months of the calendar year for each employee.
>
> Page Last Reviewed or Updated: 18-Dec-2019

This lists all the criteria which defines an ALE:

https://www.irs.gov/affordable-care-act/employers/determining-if-an-employer-is-an-applicable-large-employer

Bottom line: they don't seem to be obsolete for tax year 2019.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question of what the form is needed for in 2019